# A CMS based on Yii?

Tags: php, yii, content-management-system

i've been with Yii for a few months and before I use main CodeIgniter, SilverStripe in my projects. Does anyone know a good Yii based CMS such as SilverStripe based on Sapphire or EE based on CodeIgniter ?

My experience is working with Yii is much more easier and straightforward assuming you are good OOP coder but Yii is still young and there are not lot of samples that I can put together quickly for a real prodcution project.

A couple of YII based CMS I spotted at do not look really promising or maybe at a very early stage such as dotPlant, Web3CMS.

Comment: I recommend paying attention on http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/autoadmin/ (Yii-based CMS Framework for absolutely free designed databases)

Answer (score 9):

The developer of http://www.phundament.com/ is active over in the Yii forums.

Also, a new yii CMS has popped up that seems to be quite actively developed, and has a good feature set:
https://github.com/charlesportwoodii/CiiMS

Comment: Just released a brand new Phundament 3 extension.
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phundament/

Answer (score 5):

I agree with thaddeusmt. Yii per se is very transparent and can easily be used for complex tasks. Learning a yii-cms without good docs seems like a waste of time. You could be mastering yii itself during that time.

I mean, what's the point of learning a cms from scratch on top of learning a framework from scratch...

Answer (score 5):

We have developed a new open source Yii CMS - GXC-CMS. You can check the demo at : http://www.gxccms.com! Hope you like it

Answer (score 3):

I just found this new CMS based on Yii: [DotPlant](http://netplant.ru/); I haven't tested it yet.

**Edit:** Here a two other yii based CMSs that I found in the *extensions* section of the official site:

- [yaycms](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yaycms/)
- [ovencms](https://code.google.com/p/ovencms/)

Answer (score 3):

Would it not make sense to build the extensions that would go into making a cms so that you can easily build a cms that works the way you need it. Surely this would be the reason to use Yii rather than learning how to extend Drupal or Joomla to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

web3cms is another promising CMS based on Yii:
http://code.google.com/p/web3cms/

I don't think that there are any really mature CMS's built on Yii yet. Flexica looks like the best, but it's still not on par with Drupal or WordPress. Yii is best for developing a new application from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

FlexicaCMS is worht to look at and keep an eye on it still it become mature and ready for production.

I don't agree the idea to develop an application from scratch if you have things you can use, if so then what are Joomla and Drupal and Wordpress for ?

If you look for a Yii cms and you have time to dig the code then you can spend that time with Flexica. I can learn a couple of things from it including the user management with RBAC permission and the multilanguage implementation using Yii behavior. This is the best multilanguage implementation i have seen in fact. I a large web application which need custom parameters and parameter per module then their parameter system is very cool.

The only problem right now to me is Flexica author has not provided enough document so you should be experienced with Yii to use it. On the other hand, you can use it to learn Yii as the installation has a good company website demo.

Answer (score 0):

We released a CMS module for Yii a few days ago. It's very simple but you should check it out, it might cover you needs.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cms